# How to force tag helper for hidden fields to render bool value in lower case

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core

I have a view model with a simple bool-property like this one:

```
public bool HasAnyProductsThatRequirePhoneNumber { get; set; }
```

I'm using a tag helper to generate a HiddenField that will contain this value as in the following code:

```
<input type="hidden"
       asp-for="@this.Model.HasAnyProductsThatRequirePhoneNumber" />
```

When the page is rendered I obtain the following HTML-Code:

```
<input type="hidden" 
       id="HasAnyProductsThatRequirePhoneNumber" 
       name="HasAnyProductsThatRequirePhoneNumber" 
       value="True" />
```

As you can see, the "value"-attribute has been rendered in **uppercase (with a big T)**.

Is there any way to render it lower case? Of course I can't use something like .ToString().ToLower() since as you can see I'm specifying only the asp-for attribute manually while the value-attribute is filled automatically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. You cannot!

The code will call the `ToString` method on the boolean expression/proprety. The [`ToString` method](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/boolean.cs,90) inside boolean always returns `True` or `False`

```
public override String ToString()
{
   if (false == m_value)
   {
       return FalseLiteral;
   }
   return TrueLiteral;
 }
```

Where `TrueLiteral` and `FalseLiteral` are two variables with values such as `True` and `False`

```
internal const String TrueLiteral  = "True";
internal const String FalseLiteral = "False";
```

But that does not stop you from rendering the value as `true` or `false`. All the tag helper does is, render the markup for a input. So in your case, you can simply replace the call to the tag helper with pure html and setting the value of the input manually.

```
 <input type="hidden"  
    id="HasAnyProductsThatRequirePhoneNumber"
    name="HasAnyProductsThatRequirePhoneNumber" 
   value="@Model.HasAnyProductsThatRequirePhoneNumber.ToString().ToLower()">
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the 'value' attribute, then .ToString().ToLower() the boolean.
The revised code will be as follows:

```
<input type="hidden"
   asp-for="@this.Model.HasAnyProductsThatRequirePhoneNumber" 
   value="@this.Model.HasAnyProductsThatRequirePhoneNumber.ToString().ToLower()" />
```